# Target class [App\Http\Controllers\LoginController] does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

Laravel 6.x.
I'm creating custom multi-authentication Panels(Staff,Student,Admin) from Single Login Page.*Error already mentioned in the title.* also without using **php artisan ui bootstrap --auth**. 
*Web.php file*.

```
Route::get('/index/sign-in', function () {
    return view('log-in');
});
Route::get('/index/admin', function () {
    return view('admin-dashboard');
});
Route::get('/index/student', function () {
    return view('student-dashboard');
});
Route::get('/index/staff', function () {
    return view('faculty-dashboard');
});
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/index/dashboard/','LoginController@postlogin')->name('postlogin');
    Route::post('/index/logout','LoginController@postlogout')->name('postlogout');
});
```

*LoginController.php* file

```
    public function postlogout()
    {
        auth()->logout();
        //session()->flash('message', 'Some goodbye message');
        return redirect('/index/sign-in/');
    }
    public function postlogin()
    {
        $role=(Auth::user())->user_role;
        if ($role=='admin'){
            return 'index/admin';
        }
        elseif ($role=='staff'){
            return 'index/staff';
        }
        elseif ($role=='student'){
            return 'index/student';
        }else
        return 'index/sign-in';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the full file path of your `LoginController`?

Comment: It could be App\Http\Controllers\Auth

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BD4bN-Blw0feGQFH3D-ayFfoKOHpjWYM

Answer (score 3):

If you didn't move the controller from his default location, is inside the Auth folder, in the controller folder (app/Http/Controllers/Auth)
So as your error Target class [App\Http\Controllers\LoginController] does not exist it's searching for the controller in the Controllers folders but not in the Auth subfolder, so The route is wrong.

```
Route::post('/index/logout','LoginController@postlogout')->name('postlogout');
```

should be

```
Route::post('/index/logout','Auth\LoginController@postlogout')->name('postlogout');
```

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the default in Laravel 6, but the `LoginController` is likely under the `Auth` folder/namespace`:

```
app
- Http
-- Controllers
--- Auth
---- LoginController.php
...
```

In this case, you need to reference the namespace in your routes:

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/index/dashboard/', 'Auth\LoginController@postlogin')->name('postlogin');
    Route::post('/index/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@postlogout')->name('postlogout');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In your web.php file check all namespace passed, if their directory root is passed correctly or not.

in the upper part of web.php file you need to make sure of each controller root.
Such as you are using **LoginController** so you must pass `use App\Http\Controllers\LoginController;` or use `App\Http\Controllers\Controller\LoginController;`
according to your Http\Controller project structure

Answer (score 2):

If you did not create the controller with the artisan command, delete it and create it with the php artisan create:controller LoginController command. This should get the problem resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the namespace of the controller 
`namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;`

`class LoginController extends Controller`

Comment: if your login controller is inside auth folder then it'll be the same namespace else if it's not inside the folder then it'll be only `namespace App\Http\Controllers`

Answer (score 1):

All the above solution didn't work for me, what did was using

> php artisan route:clear